# Flex Spark form, horizontally aligning form items

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

This is the scenario:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Form>
            <s:FormItem label="label1">
                <s:TextInput/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="label2">
                <s:TextInput/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="label3">
                <s:TextInput/>
            </s:FormItem>
        </s:Form>
        <s:Form>
            <s:FormItem label="label1">
                <s:Label text="soemthing"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="label2">
                <s:Label text="soemthing"/>
            </s:FormItem>
            <s:FormItem label="label3">
                <s:Label text="soemthing"/>
            </s:FormItem>
        </s:Form>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

And the question is, which would be the right way to align each formItem of the left form with the ones on the right form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TileLayout` for your form:

> [image: tile-layout]

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Form>
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="2"
                          verticalAlign="middle" />
        </s:layout>

        <s:FormItem label="label1">
            <s:TextInput />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="label1">
            <s:Label text="something" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="label2">
            <s:TextInput />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="label2">
            <s:Label text="something" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="label3">
            <s:TextInput />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="label3">
            <s:Label text="something" />
        </s:FormItem>

    </s:Form>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: This layout works fine when the label text for all fields has the same length. When label text lengths vary then TextInput controls do not appear aligned. How can the TextInputs appear aligned?