# Flex spark FormLayout on TileLayout columns

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I always end up hard-coding things that appear to be so simple...

This is the scenario:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:Form>
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="2"
                          verticalAlign="middle" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:FormItem label="Label with long text">
            <s:TextInput />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Label with long text">
            <s:Label text="something" />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="shortLabel">
            <s:TextInput />
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="shortLabel">
            <s:Label text="something" />
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:Application>
```

Is there a simple way to give each tile layout column a FormLayout?

In form layout, all the first items on FormItem containers are aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overridden form layout that's why elements are not aligned correctly.

As I understand you need multi columns form. Flex doesn't support such functionality now.
Possible solutions are:
1. Use 2 forms in container. In such case form items would be aligned.
2. Define form items sizes.
3. Write you own new multi column form layout and share it.

Comment: I'm currently using a custom variable column tile layout with HGroups as the items, but since this is no longer a form, i lost the warning icons showing with validators... after fixing em to apear right after the last component in formItem container with a custom skinClass, im not using it cuz of this

Comment: Oh, and i had a this problem with solution one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091763/flex-spark-form-horizontally-aligning-form-items
Someone suggested me the TileLayout, which came with new problems...

Comment: Making a multi columns form looks like the only way to go to achieve what i am asking for, so i am closing this with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spark FormLayout extends VerticalLayout, changing its inheritance to TileLayout in customLayout class(say FormTileLayout)  worked for my project.